# Select * from 'many to many' SQL relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

I'm still learning SQL and my brain is having a hard time with this one.

Say I have 3 tables:

```
teams
players
```

and `teams_players` as my link table

All I want to do is run a query to get each team and the players on them.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
INNER JOIN teams_players 
    ON teams.id = teams_players.team_id 
INNER JOIN players 
    ON teams_players.player_id = players.id
```

But it returned a separate row for each player on each team. Is JOIN the right way to do it or should I be doing something else?

----------------------------------------- Edit

Ok, so from what I'm hearing, this isn't necessarily a bad way to do it. I'll just have to group the data by team while I'm doing my loop.

I have not yet tried the modified SQL statements provided, but I will today and get back to you.

To answer the question about structure - I guess I wasn't thinking about the returned row structure which is part of what lead to my confusion. In this particular case, each team is limited to 4 players (or less) so I guess the structure that would be helpful to me is something like the following:

```
teams.id, teams.name, players.id, players.name, players.id, players.name, players.id, players.name, players.id, players.name,
1         Team ABC    1           Jim           2           Bob           3            Ned          4             Roy
2         Team XYZ    2           Bob           3           Ned           5            Ralph        6             Tom
```

Comment: Edited your sql to make it more readable on screen if you dont mind

Comment: This seems like expected behavior. Can you give an example of the sort of result row you're expecting? I don't see how to return a team and all its players as a row in a result set.

Comment: If you want the results for a particular team - you need to add a `WHERE` clause that limits the results to a particular team. Oh and `SELECT *` is frowned upon by most DBA's so you should specify the columns that you want

Comment: @AdrianCornish: While I get the point for a large database with complex table structures and all, it can be helpful for a beginner (myself included) to spot errors when you can see all the fields without having to list every field you need.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Good point and valid too - but there is also the lesson of selecting what you want - if you do not know then maybe you do not understand your own problem :-). I have a feeling the OP needs to group results which requires picking columns to make the results mean something.

Comment: @AdrianCornish thanks for formatting my sql!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is a guess but you want a team and the list of the players in the team on one row

How about

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id)
FROM teams t
INNER JOIN teams_players tp
    ON t.id = tp.team_id 
INNER JOIN players p
    ON tp.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Manual may help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for. Puts all of the players together as a string which I can easily explode out if I need to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will return data in a table format, so think about how you would return a list of players and teams, including which team each player is associated with, in one table/result set without returning a separate row for each player on the team?

Your query should return:

```
team.id, team.name, player.id, player.name
1        team1      1          player1
1        team1      2          player2
2        team2      3          player3
2        team2      4          player4
```

If you want something like

```
team.id, team.name
1        team1
2        team2

player.id, player.name, team.id
1          player1      1
2          player2      1
3          player3      2
4          player4      2
```

Which has two separate result sets, then you'll have to make two queries. If you want a different result set for each team, you'll have to make an additional query for each team.

That being said, I don't see anything too too wrong with your initial query except that it's giving you a lot of duplicate data in exchange for not having to make multiple queries.

Comment: This was helpful - I wasn't giving thought to the returned structure having to be consistent. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I don't know if you can do what you're asking, see Adrian Cornish's answer to put all players in a single column.